# How do I use System.Activities.Validation.GetParentChain?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've got an Outer activity which has a Body onto which you drag other activities.  I then have several Inner activities, which MUST be a descendent of an Outer activity.  I'd like to add design-time validation to ensure the Inner is placed within an Outer.

I've heard that I "[can use System.Activities.Validation.GetParentChain to enumerate all of the parents of an activity during the validation step](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/5518c991-5075-403a-911d-bcd480e2f769)".  But even after reading [the documentation for the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.validation.getparentchain.aspx), I have no idea how to use it.

I would think I use it inside CacheMetadata in my Inner class.  I'd like to use have a foreach(var ancestor in parentChain) { ... }, and make sure at least one ancestor is of type Outer.  Not sure how to do that.

Can anyone explain how to validate at design time that an Inner activity is a descendant of an Outer activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.validation.getparentchain.aspx) `GetParentChain` is a regular `CodeActivity`. You can use it in conjunction with [`Activity.Constraints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activity.constraints.aspx).

Constraints are executed at design time, just like `CacheMetadata()`, but you have the ability to access the context (the *ValidationContext* at this point, of course). Otherwise you wouldn't be able to known the upper level activities.

Lets see if I understood your case right and if this example covers it. Basically it loops through `IEnumerable<Activity>` returned by `GetParentChain` and checks if any of *Inner*'s parents is an *Outer*. This way it ensures that *Inner* is always inside an *Outer*.

```
public sealed class Inner : CodeActivity
{

    public Inner()
    {
        Constraints.Add(MustBeInsideOuterActivityConstraint());
    }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Execution logic here
    }

    private Constraint<Inner> MustBeInsideOuterActivityConstraint()
    {
        var activityBeingValidated = new DelegateInArgument<Inner>();
        var validationContext = new DelegateInArgument<ValidationContext>();
        var parent = new DelegateInArgument<Activity>();
        var parentIsOuter = new Variable<bool>();

        return new Constraint<Inner>
        {
            Body = new ActivityAction<Inner, ValidationContext>
            {
                Argument1 = activityBeingValidated,
                Argument2 = validationContext,

                Handler = new Sequence
                {
                    Variables = 
                    {
                        parentIsOuter
                    },
                    Activities =
                    {
                        new ForEach<Activity>
                        {
                            Values = new GetParentChain 
                            { 
                                ValidationContext = validationContext 
                            },

                            Body = new ActivityAction<Activity>
                            {
                                Argument = parent,

                                Handler = new If
                                {
                                    Condition = new InArgument<bool>(env => 
                                        object.Equals(parent.Get(env).GetType(), typeof(Outer))),

                                    Then = new Assign<bool> 
                                    { 
                                        To = parentIsOuter, 
                                        Value = true 
                                    }
                                }    
                            }
                        },

                        new AssertValidation
                        {
                            Assertion = parentIsOuter,
                            Message = "Inner must be inside Outer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If you want to allow multiple Outers, you have to check them, one by one, wither with a loop through an array (using ForEach) or multiple nested Ifs.

For example, with multiple ifs, and continuing with the code above:

```
Handler = new If
{
    Condition = new InArgument<bool>(env => 
        object.Equals(parent.Get(env).GetType(), typeof(OuterONE))),

    Then = new Assign<bool> 
    { 
        To = parentIsOuter, 
        Value = true 
    }
    Else = new If
    {
         Condition = new InArgument<bool>(env => 
             object.Equals(parent.Get(env).GetType(), typeof(OuterTWO))),

         Then = new Assign<bool> 
         { 
            To = parentIsOuter, 
            Value = true 
         },

         Else = new If 
         {
             // and continue with other Outers
         }
    }
}
```

In short, an If-then-else statement using activities.

Other option that I've never tested but that it seems pretty plausible, and because you can use activities inside constraints, is throw all this logic inside an activity which its only job is to check if type if an Outer:

```
public sealed CheckIfTypeIsOuter<T> : CodeActivity<bool>
{
    protected override bool Execute() 
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Outer1))
            return true;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Outer2))
            return true;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Outer3))
            return true;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Outer4))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

This way you can do it through code.

Well, I guess you get the idea!

Comment: Wow, thanks, this looks complicated. So we have to create new activities to validate our activities?? Why is GetParentChain an activity!?

Comment: I'm completely new to these constraints so I was surprised by it at first.  But, this looks like it works, thanks!

Comment: Now, what if I want to have several possible Outers (OuterA OR OuterB OR OuterC), provided by an input type array?  I've tried to set the Condition to the result of some static function, but it doesn't allow me to do this unless I write it inline.

Comment: It looks complicated at first but it's pretty simple. Because of its simplicity it's also, in my opinion, somehow limited. I'm really not sure why GetParentChain, just like a bunch of other validation conditions are activities but my guess is to allow serialization of constraints to XAML together with the activities that they constrain although I haven't seen such case in action. BTW, you've more validation conditions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.validation.aspx).

Comment: And that's your first collision with constraints limitations. You've do declare it all inside the constraint activity just like you were writing code but declaratively, using activities. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble implementing this, because I don't want a hard-coded set of typeof(OuterX).  I want to pass a Type array, and validate that it is one of those types.  All of my attempts at doing this gave me errors with passing reference types in Literal<T>.

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing the actual code. Anyway, at some point you've to declare that array, even if only once, or inside the constraint, or inside a custom activity or wherever you want. Why don't you wrap all those Outers with an interface, i.e. *IOuter*? Then the *Condition* would just check for that interface through *typeof(IOuter)*. It's a much cleaner, direct and better solution and future Outers you add wouldn't break anything.

Comment: Thanks, I think the interface idea is probably a good idea.  Unfortunate that we can't send reference values into a constraint, though.

Comment: Here's some more documentation to go along with it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/declarative-constraints

Answer (score 0):

[Joao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8018098/9211387) is great. I took his answer and made the constraint dynamic so I could reuse it across 20+ activities without adding 80+ lines of code to each one.

The constraint is placed in it's own file `ScopeActivityConstraint.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Activities.Validation;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Constraints
    {
        public static Constraint<T> ScopeActivity<T>(
          object activity,
          object scope,
          string message
        )
        {
            var delegateType = typeof(DelegateInArgument<>).MakeGenericType(activity.GetType());
            dynamic activityBeingValidated = Activator.CreateInstance(delegateType);

            var validationContext = new DelegateInArgument<ValidationContext>();
            var parent = new DelegateInArgument<Activity>();
            var insideScope = new Variable<bool>();

            Sequence handler = new Sequence
            {
                Variables = {
                    insideScope
                },
                Activities =
                {
                    new ForEach<Activity>
                    {
                        Values = new GetParentChain 
                        { 
                            ValidationContext = validationContext 
                        },

                        Body = new ActivityAction<Activity>
                        {
                            Argument = parent,

                            Handler = new If
                            {
                                Condition = new InArgument<bool>(env => 
                                    object.Equals(parent.Get(env).GetType(), scope)),

                                Then = new Assign<bool> 
                                { 
                                    To = insideScope, 
                                    Value = true 
                                }
                            }    
                        }
                    },

                    new AssertValidation
                    {
                        Assertion = insideScope,
                        Message = message
                    }
                }
            };

            var activityActionType = typeof(ActivityAction<,>).MakeGenericType(
                activity.GetType(),
                typeof(ValidationContext)
            );
            dynamic constraintBody = Activator.CreateInstance(activityActionType);
            constraintBody.Argument1 = activityBeingValidated;
            constraintBody.Argument2 = validationContext;
            constraintBody.Handler = handler;

            var constraintType = typeof(Constraint<>).MakeGenericType(activity.GetType());
            dynamic constraint = Activator.CreateInstance(constraintType);
            constraint.Body = constraintBody;

            return constraint;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then utilize it in your `Inner` activity:

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Validation;
using static MyNamespace.Constraints;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Inner : CodeActivity
    {
        public Inner()
        {
            Constraint<Inner> constraint = ScopeActivity<Inner>(
                this,
                typeof(MyNamespace.OuterScope),
                "Inner activity must be placed inside an Outer Scope activity",
            );
            Constraints.Add(constraint);
        }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // do things
        }
    }
}
```