# WF4: Validate that all exit statuses of activity has transitions to other activities

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

We are trying to change our business process so that it is implemented via WF4.
Our business process looks like this:

- There are a number of handlers.
- Each handler has a number of output statuses.
- Handlers are implemented as Activities
- Designers will support output statuses of these activities so that

  - we can easily see what statuses cause what next activities
  - we can validate at compile time that all statuses of each activity are connected with some other activity.

How can we achieve this in WF4?

Comment: You can use [state machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.statemachine.aspx) available in .NET 4.5.  However, I don't know how to accomplish transition validation, thus this is a comment.  If someone can answer how you validate all states are connected, they have your answer.

Comment: Thank you, Will, I'm already usign .net 4.0.1 and state machines from it. But the core of the question is the very validation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with StateMachine but validation at design-time is achieved with activity constraints. My guess is that it is no different with StateMachines. Check my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016606/how-do-i-use-system-activities-validation-getparentchain/8018098#8018098) question for an introduction and example.

Comment: Thank you, @Jota, I will definetely look at you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define required properties (the transition activities) in your handler activities. Then in the handler's **CacheMetadata** override you can validate whether they are provided or not. And at the end of your handler activity's **Execute** method you can schedule the assigned transition activity with the workflow runtime. Something like the following:

```
public sealed class MyHandlerActivity : NativeActivity
{
    public MyHandlerActivity NextHandler
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        // Ensure next handler is supplied.
        if (this.NextHandler == null)
        {
            metadata.AddValidationError("Next handler is not assigned.");
            return;
        }

        // Let the workflow runtime that this activity could schedule another activity (the handler activity).
        metadata.AddChild(this.NextHandler);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        // TODO: Handler should do something here.

        // Schedule the next handler.
        context.ScheduleActivity(this.NextHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I do not want my activity to know what activity should be scheduled next. And also what should I do when there are several next activities, from which we should select only one by some condition in state machine?